# How to publich chrome extension in private network?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I want to publish an chrome extension under private network of our domain 'somedomain.com'.

After uploading the zip file of extension i get to edit the information. I also get the following message :

```
A one-time developer registration fee of US$5.00 is required to verify your account and publish items.  - Learn more
The fee is not required to publish only to users in somedomain.com.
```

If they have said fee is not required to publish only to users under specific domain, Then what is the appropriate step to publish this way?
when i click on publish changes it redirects me to the page asking for payment and forces me to pay to get my extension published under private  network.

So anyone tell me how to (step wise step) publish an extension privately without any need of debit card.
PS : one of our user inside our network has already paid the registration fee, however i have not paid any fee.